# What are some techniques to make paragraphs look clean, organized and easier to read?

Tags: html, css

When I make paragraphs I want them to be as easy as possible to read and to understand quickly. Unfortunately though my paragraphs end up something like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000   
0000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000
000000000.
```

When the ideal would be like this:

```
  000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000
000000000.
```

What are some techniques I could use in html and css to make my ideal come true? What do you usually do?

Comment: First of all, study typography, then think how to adjust your CSS.

Comment: styling of paragraph depends on the designs

Comment: How do your paragraphs end up as the former?  Can you show a real example?  There may be some small changes we can suggest based on your existing code.

Comment: That style of paragraph you want is called "justified"

Comment: p {text-align:justify} will justify you paragraph, but I challenge you to find any site on the web that actually formats their paragraphs in the way you're asking.

Comment: @PeteLeaning Here is one, http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/. Notice how its not exactly aligned and some words can be hard to read at times?

Comment: Justifying text on the web [does not make it more readable](http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/articles/Pages/justified_text.aspx).  Not until we get 300DPI displays and proper kerning, anyway.

Comment: @robertc Thank you, will be reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your "ideal" output, you can use something like this:

```
p {
    text-indent:1em;  
    text-align:justify;
}
```

However, you should absolutely do some research on typography before you decide that this is the one-size-fits-all solution to your problems. Readability has a lot of factors (font size, family, color, background, line-height, width of content, etc.) and I'd be surprised if justified text alignment is part of the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/EUUN4/

```
    <div style="text-align:justify;width:200px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CSS references that would be a good place to start - [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)